# The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s);

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have a simple `ExternalAccount` entity:

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class ExternalAccount
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string APIKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and an `AppUser` entity that has a one-to-many relationship with the `ExternalAccount`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Domain
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<ExternalAccount> ExternalAccounts { get; set; } = new List<ExternalAccount>();
    }
}
```

My `DataContext` class is also pretty straightforward:

```
using Domain;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Persistence
{
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ExternalAccount> ExternalAccounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now for simplicity I have a method that contains the following:

```
var user = await _context.Users.Include(p => p.ExternalAccounts).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == "Bob");

if (user == null) return null;

ExternalAccount account = new ExternalAccount
{
    Id = Guid.Parse("08186b29-e603-4cc8-9575-47b237775274"),
    APIKey = "some long text here",
};

user.ExternalAccounts.Add(account);

var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
```

After hitting the last line I'm getting a

```
"statusCode": 500,
"message": "The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.",
```

While debugging if I hover over `user.ExternalAccounts.Add(account);` it looks like the account has been added.

[image]

Any idea what could be the problem here?

Edit 1: Not solved, I was looking over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key and read that "Including just one navigation property (no inverse navigation, and no foreign key property) is enough to have a relationship defined by convention." I've considered that there might be a problem with the "conventional way" so I tried to explicitly define the relationship:

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class ExternalAccount
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string APIKey { get; set; }

        public string AppUserForeignKey { get; set; }

        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
using Domain;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Persistence
{
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<ExternalAccount> ExternalAccounts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ExternalAccount>()
                .HasOne(u => u.AppUser)
                .WithMany(a => a.ExternalAccounts)
                .HasForeignKey(k => k.AppUserForeignKey);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.LogTo(message => Debug.WriteLine(message));
    }
}
```

This still returned the same error.

Added some logging as suggested below in the comments.

The migration looks like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/gLs1suBT

The logging: https://pastebin.com/raw/GH8V2Y9q

Comment: Please include how `AppUser` and `ExternalAccount` are related in the DB and include the relationship mapping from EF. I would expect a one-to-many here, one `AppUser` can have 0 to many `ExternalAccount` instances. I do not see any code with a FK that makes this relationship possible or mapping in your EF instance.

Comment: And add logging to see the SQL sent to the database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging

Comment: @Igor I was checking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key and found "Including just one navigation property (no inverse navigation, and no foreign key property) is enough to have a relationship defined by convention." Is it recommended to define the one to many relationship myself in this case?

Comment: It could be that because there are explicit mappings that are specified in `IdentityDbContext<T>` that this convention is ignored on the `AppUser` type. I would try to specify the mappings explicitly and see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: hmm... assigning a list collection to a navigation property -- and that property not being virtual to begin with -- seems problematic.  For me, I'm a bit puzzled as to what this error message is.  Why are you getting a 500 status code? is this dbcontext over API?  are you not receiving an EF exception nor database exception as it relates to the handling of that kind of response?

Comment: @Igor Defining the relationship explicitly did not work, same result. Included logging and the migration above.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft Added logging as suggested.

Comment: It's trying to Update the ExternalAccount rather than INSERT it.  Debug and look at all your tracked entities and make sure you see what you expect.  IE only one user with their ExternalAccounts.  And is ExternalAccount.id a text value in the database?

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem.
I am trying to add an owned (many) object to an entity.
And it says no rows are being updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for all the helpful comments. It led me in the right direction.

The problem was that by generating my Id's manually, the new entity got the `Modified` state, instead of `Added` state. The fix was using the Fluent API's `.ValueGeneratedNever()` method with the `modelBuilder`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ExternalAccount>()
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedNever();
        }
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#detectchanges-honors-store-generated-key-values

Comment: I was migrating from Int to Guid, lost 4 hours, this is a confusing issues, Thanks

Comment: Your answer just saved me a bit of headache!

Answer (score 0):

Before saving your changes in your dbcontext, you need to update the users table:

```
await _context.Users.Update(user);
```

Call the above-mentioned piece before SaveChangesAsync() attempt.